# Reducing Number of Params in Factory Class GetObj

Tags: c#, parameters, factory, factory-pattern

This is a general question, which is why there is not much code below. I have looked on stackoverflow and do not see the solution (could have missed it).

In a general sense, if my GetObj within the class factory looks like below, is there a better way to feed the parameter information to the constructors of the objects being created within GetObj? Each of the constructors uses a different subset of the parameters being passed into GetObj. For clarity I am currently used named parameters for passing them, but there are just so many parameters that it seems like there should be a better solution for clarity. Any ideas (e.g. use of structure would be one idea)? Can other patterns be employed? Thanks.

```
public class <FactoryName>
{
     static public <InterfaceName> GetObj(
            <type1> <param1>,
            <type2> <param2>,
            <type3> <param3>,
            <type4> <param4>,
            <type5> <param5>,
            <type6> <param6>) 
    {...}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating factory object based on these many parameters doesn't sounds good, i feel you need to re-factor this approach and need to simplify. But in this case, structure/class will do. If all the parameters are of same type, generic collection will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What are some possible approaches for refactoring (if any come to mind)? Thanks.

Comment: @Buck, re-factor is purely depends on your requirement and code you have written, but check Abstract Factory Patterns. It may help you in your case.

Comment: Thanks Mohanavel! I looked at it, but it looks like the challenge is still getting the information into the class method that does the object creation. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than passing in a long list of parameters, you could pass in a map (key-value pairs).  This has the added advantage (or disadvantage, depending on how you look at it) of allowing parameters to be optional simply by not including them in the map.

One of the challenges with this approach over explicit parameters is keeping the documentation accurate - what are the keys for the map properties, and which ones are required vs optional.

Comment: Interesting Chris. I see what you mean by keeping the documentation correct. I will give this more thought. I think in, at least, some cases this would be extremely useful. Thanks!